# Want to redirect my site all pages to /blog

Tags: htaccess, redirects

For example my site: `www.example.com`

When anyone visits my site, I want them all to redirect to `www.example.com/blog`

But when I open my site it should not redirect me to blog, it should work normally. So how can I achieve the above using .htaccess?

I am going to apply the following code to redirect all pages to `blog`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/blog? [L,R=301]
```

But how can I specify my IP address in above so I can access all pages and no redirects.

Comment: I've just answered below, however, I've just realised that I might have misinterpreted your question!? So to confirm... are you wanting all other users (apart from yourself; your IP address) to be redirected to `/blog/`? The URL in the address bar should show `/blog/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect everyone else, apart from your IP address (eg. `123.123.123.123`), to the `/blog` subdirectory then you can use something like the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.123.123.123
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the requested URI does not start with `/blog/` and the IP address is not `123.123.123.123` then redirect to include `/blog/` at the start.

The `$1` in the `RewriteRule` substitution is a backreference to the parenthesised pattern `(.*)` in the `RewriteRule` pattern (ie. the entire URL less the slash prefix - in htaccess).

Note also that I've removed the `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution. This specifically removes any query string from the request. Unless that is required, it should be omitted.

I don't see any reason to test against `%{HTTP_HOST}` (as in your original example). (?)

---

My initial answer (below) is not what you require, but I'll leave it for completeness.

This version *internally rewrites* (as opposed to *redirecting*) all requests to the `/blog` subdirectory (the URL in the address bar does not change).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1 [L]
```

This basically says... if the requested URI does not start with `/blog/` then rewrite to include `/blog/` at the start. Note the absence of the `R` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive. The `R` flag would result in an *external redirect*.

Comment: Of course this is an automatic up-vote!! Total trust in your answers. Looks dang good to me!

Comment: @closetnoc Well, I'm actually wondering whether I've misinterpreted the question and the OP wants an external redirect after all - just not when they access the site?! This would also tie in with the IP address reference.

Comment: I missed that too! Assuming one site on one IP address and no catch-all site, I would assume that entering an IP address should do what he wants with your code. As well, your /blog/$1 on your RewriteRule assumes that example.com/sugarshack/ would have the page example.com/blog/sugarshack/ which may not always be the case. Something to ask the OP along with some configuration probing. Regex in .htaccess is not always easy is it?? ;-)

Comment: @w3d        Thank you for answer , Yes I want to specify my IP address so when I open site from my PC it should not redirect and for all other public it should redirect..

Comment: @rahulbhatt I've updated my answer. (Sorry for the mix up!)